# How to get the current table row without using an event handler?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a boostrap modal along with a event handler and basically whenever the user clicks on the editLocationBtn the modal appears which its supposed to do. I was wondering if there is a way without having to use an event handler of getting the current row, so that I can update that row after the user clicks on save? I've tried removing the document on click event handler but I couldn't get the current row.

HMTL

```
<td><button type = button data-bs-toggle=modal class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editLocationBtn" data-bs-target=#editLocationModal></button></td>
```

This is the JS

```
$("#editLocationModal").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {  
$(document).on('click','.editLocationBtn',function (e) {
    currentVal = ($(this).closest('tr').find('td')[0])
   
  });
})
```

Comment: What would you define as "the current row" if the user can't click or otherwise interact with it to select which is the "current row"?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to add a class to the row when it is selected, eg `$("tr").on("click", function() { $(".selected").removeClass("selected"); $(this).addClass("selected"); })` then when they click [save] you can get the previously-selected row with `$("tr.selected")`

Comment: What I meant by current row was the row that was being clicked on by that button if that makes sense.

Comment: ie, the row that was the last one to be clicked on - add an "active" class to the row (you can also style it so the user knows which row they are working with)